# Compare tty/pts ssh session between Unix client & server

Tags: tty

Is it possible to list ssh session with tty/pts info and date of login and logout on a client ? equivalent of last command on a server.

My users use a proxy ssh to connect to a server, but from proxy server they use a generic account to connect to server.
I would to compare tty/pts id between client and server.
On the server I use this script to obtain this info for the current day :

```
#!/bin/bash
today="$(date '+%a %b %e')"
last | awk -v pattern="$today" '$0 ~ pattern && /pts/ {print $0 "#line#"}'
exit 0
```

Thanks

Comment: If I well understand the _client_ in this case is the proxy server. And you have access to it. Can you confirm it? (If so you can run the same script on the client). BTW It seems to me that you want to control somehow the activity of your clients because they all log to the same account on the proxy. If so you should ask it directly. Ps>welcome on SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks, yes my proxy is my client and I have access to it. If I run the same script on the proxy (client), I have history of connections of user computer to proxy but not proxy to server. But may be I miss something. From users computers to proxy they use their own SSH account but from proxy to server, they use a generic account (ex : oracle).

Comment: You're welcome. Again what is your real (final) question? ;) ? If you want to control the access to a program on the server create different users for the program. If not possible create different users on the server and allow them to change identity to the allowed user, or to execute that program as that user (see the _holy_ `sudo`). For the path you're imaging you need to match the two lists, or better to enable ssh logging and match that two lists. But you will not have 100% unique  matches.

Comment: the context is : I work for a customer to audit access on DB server. I use a Database Activity Monitoring solution, but in addition I would to log user on OS level. Today, this customer use a ssh proxy to connect to the DB server with a generic account. I can't change their work process, I'm agree from security point of view it's very bad practices. My real question is : I would to compare tty/pts from the client side with the server side and to correlate the timestamp.

Comment: You have an answer... I don't know if you will like but it is an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **In few words**

Use the logs of ssh on both machines: it gives you the PID of the shell spawned. This should allow you to connect the PID of the shell with the execution of the program and to have a certain match with the tty. For a deeper audit you can use an audit tool.

### **In more words**

#### **`last`**

With the simple `last` you can have the list of the connections related with the tty used.
You can have two list one from your *proxy* machine (I would like to call it Gateway, GW), and the other from your *server*.
The command `last` by default give you username, pts/tty, IP/hostname. *log-in* date-time, *log-out* date-time.  You can modify in format, etc. etc.

Then you have to work on the overlays of the period and guess who was.

The problem that I see is that in this way you have to create a tool (script) that gives you all the possible matches, and purge them meanwhile you find good matches. Nonetheless, you can have strange situations.

Let's do a case study. A first user, let we say Nicolas, can log on the GW. Then he goes to take a coffee or answers to a call. Meanwhile a second user, let we say Hastur, log-in the GW and faster then the 1<sup>st</sup> user logs to the server. Just in this moment your double log is intricate. Now Hastur feels the need of a coffee and Nicolas logs to the server. Who will be the first that will finish the coffee and that will connect for first with the program?

#### **`/var/log/auth`** (or other log file of ssh)<sup>[[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127432/logging-ssh-access-attempts)]</sup>..

There are log files used to monitor the login and logout on each system. Search for the right path and name, those ca system depending. With

```
sudo grep TheUsername /var/log/auth.log
```

you will obtain lines similar to

```
May  1 16:17:43 owl sshd[9024]: Accepted publickey for root from 192.168.0.101 port 37384 ssh2
May  1 16:17:43 owl sshd[9024]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

where you have the right login time, and even the PID (`[9024]`), and the IP.
This time you can match the data of this file with the one of `last` command to know the tty, or you can have somehow logged inside the program the PID of the shell that called the program itself (it is possible to do with a system call to the shell).

Working on those files you can have a unique match for each session. For the analogous log file on the gateway you will have the original IP and username.

#### **`audit tools`**<sup>[[2](https://serverfault.com/q/111090)],[[3](https://serverfault.com/q/25595)]</sup>

If you have the authorization to do and it is legal, you can use an audit tool and do a full log of the shell on the host machine.

References

- [[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127432/logging-ssh-access-attempts)] Logging SSH access attempts
- [[2](https://serverfault.com/q/111090)] shell / ssh / tty session logger
- [[3](https://serverfault.com/q/25595)] BASH shell session logging on remote host